# why I am getting an error on internet explore element?

Tags: excel, vba

Why am I getting an error?

> Object doesn't support this property or method

[image]

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is only defined on `document`, not `HTMLElement`. Instead use `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` is only defined on `document`, not `HTMLElement`. [Instead use `querySelectorAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/cc288511(v=vs.85)).

You should also use intermediate variables so you can inspect your program when debugging without having multiple calls on the same line and then not-knowing which specific call failed.

Like so:

```
Dim contentElement
Set contentElement = IE.GetElementById( "content" )
If contentElement = Nothing Then
    MsgBox( "<div#content> not found" )
End If

Dim postTitles
Set postTitles = contentElement.QuerySelectorAll( ".post-title" )

Dim postTitle
For Each postTitle in postTitles
    
    ' do stuff
Next
```